# magento 1.9.2.3 admin login not working

Tags: magento-1.9, admin

magento 1.9.2.3 admin login not working
http://127.0.0.1/xxxxxxxxx/index.php/admin/index/index/key/0be5e3803ecd74044d4e1ac161ad3226/

project run on server fine but locahost not working
[image: admin login Here]

Comment: Did you change the base url of the site?

Comment: web/unsecure/base_url   web/secure/base_url  change to http://127.0.0.1/xxxxxxxx/

Comment: front end is working ah?

Comment: Try to navigate in your database and look for core_config_data table and change the base_url secure and unsecure change it to 127.0.0.1/xxxxxxx .

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem in local server.

You can fix it by creating editing the hosts file (http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/) to map a domain to 127.0.0.1.

For example:
127.0.0.1 local.mage.dev

After this you will need update your store URL in database, since your admin is not working.

To do this, run the following queries replacing the xxxxxxxxx by your store directory:

```
UPDATE core_config_data SET value = 'http://local.mage.dev/xxxxxxxxx/' WHERE path = 'web/unsecure/base_url';
UPDATE core_config_data SET value = 'http://local.mage.dev/xxxxxxxxx/' WHERE path = 'web/secure/base_url';
```

Comment: 127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1       local.mage.dev    set  hosts file  and  core_config_data ,web/secure/base_url  http://local.mage.dev/directory/  but not working admin login  / end of directory

Comment: Try doing that in incognito mode or another browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try to login from `Firefox`. if you are using chrome, most of the time it won't let you in.

Answer (score 0):

happens with me most of the time

Delete cookies always solve my problem.

if you want to delete only one cookie then you can delete `adminhtml` cookie from your browser

and login works

Answer (score 0):

It has multiple reasons:

```
You need to check the Nginx hosts whether it's correct or not. because when PHP not getting the correct permissions it causes this problem.

You need to check the core_config_table to put your local host there.

If you use this command nginx -t it shows you the reasons why Nginx is not working correctly.
```